# Junk data in C# OracleDataAdapter

Tags: c#, oracle, dataset, dataadapter

I am executing a query using `OracleDataAdapter` and taking the result into a `DataSet` in a C# application.

Below is code:

```
var da =new OracleDataAdapter("select login_id, session_key, ipaddress from
                              login_request_table where status='active'", ocon);
var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
foreach (DataRow drRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
  var mLoginId = drRow["Login_id"].ToString();
  var session = drRow["session_key"].ToString();
  var ipadd = drRow["ipaddress"].ToString();
 }
```

When I executes this, first I confirmed any record in my Oracle table and result is:

[image: Oracle query result]

So as we can see there is no record in table for `active` status.

Now the hectic part:

When I debug the same query in Visual Studio, I am getting lots of records. Don't know why.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

Some times the autocommit in Oracle, may be disabled. So, once the update has been done, you must do Commit if you run the queries through Backend.  Try writing [Commit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4010.htm) after executing Update and check once.